# django-celery-beat loading task but celery worker not receiving it

Tags: django, celery, worker, celerybeat, elastic-mq

I've been having these issues on my celery beat and worker where my celery beat creates task, but celery worker does not receive it. I am using elasticmq as the broker

My celery beat logs

It does not pick up the tasks from celery beat, here is the snippet of the task

```
app = Celery("app")
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

CELERY_CONFIG = {
    "CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT": ["json"],
    "CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER": "json",
    "CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND": None,
    "CELERY_ENABLE_UTC": True,
    "CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL": False,
}

BROKER_URL = "sqs://user:password@sqs:9324/"

CELERY_CONFIG.update(
    {
        "BROKER_URL": BROKER_URL,
        "BROKER_TRANSPORT": "sqs",
        "BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS": {
            "region": "us-west-2",
            "use_ssl": False,
            "visibility_timeout": 3600,
            "polling_interval": 60,
        },
    }
)

app.conf.update(**CELERY_CONFIG)
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
```

and here is the task,

```
@celery.app.task()
def beat_task() -> None:
    logger.info("Starting beat task...")
    time.sleep(2)
    logger.info("Done beat task.")
```

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "beat_task": {
        "task": "app.tasks.beat_task",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=10),
    },
}
```

I am not getting the logger info print result on worker

Tried connecting celery worker and beat, did not work

Here are some screenshots

[image: Screenshot of the celery worker]

[![Screenshot of the beat sending queues][2]][2]

[![Nothing received from the worker][3]][3]
Screenshot of the celery worker

Screenshot of the beat sending queues
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpjDn.png
Nothing received from the worker
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skRL8.png

Answer (score 0):

the `celery.app` object is not defined here.the Celery object is here initialized with the name `app` and not `celery.app`.
so change the decorator to `@app.task()`.

```
app = Celery("app")
logger = get_task_logger(__name__).....

@app.task()
def beat_task().....
```

update any other references from `celery.app` in your code to `app`